how to invoke rag chain with two input?
I'm trying to invoke the rag chain with two input variable but I'm getting error.
def get_data_from_llm(raw_text):

    # Initialize the LLM and create a chain
    llm = Together(
        model="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1",
        temperature=0.7,
        max_tokens=2048,
        top_k=1,
        together_api_key="api_key_here",
    )
    # chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template,          output_parser=JsonOutputParser(pydantic_object=InvoiceJSON))
   
    json_parser = SimpleJsonOutputParser(pydantic_object=InvoiceJSON)

    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["raw_text"],
        template="'raw_text': {raw_text},\n'json_structure': {json_structure}",
        partial_variables={"json_structure": json_parser.get_format_instructions()},
    )

    few_shot_prompt = FewShotPromptTemplate(
        examples=few_shot_examples,
        example_prompt=prompt_template,
        prefix=json_prefix,
        suffix=suffix,
        input_variables=['json_structure']
    )
  
    # Run the chain with the raw text
    chain = {"raw_text": RunnablePassthrough(), "json_structure": RunnableLambda(get_structure)} | few_shot_prompt | llm #| json_parser
    chain_data = chain.invoke(raw_text)
    print(chain_data)
    return chain_data

for the above code I'm getting this error below
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\utils.py", line 136, in <module>
    print(create_docs('Deccan Sources - 1173 - 12.12.22_12122022113240_15122022184846.pdf'))
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\utils.py", line 116, in create_docs
    llm_extracted_data = get_data_from_llm(raw_data)
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\examples.py", line 127, in get_data_from_llm
    chain_data = chain.invoke(raw_text)
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 2493, in invoke
    input = step.invoke(
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\base.py", line 128, in invoke
    return self._call_with_config(
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 1620, in _call_with_config
    context.run(
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\config.py", line 347, in call_func_with_variable_args
    return func(input, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\base.py", line 112, in _format_prompt_with_error_handling
    return self.format_prompt(**_inner_input)
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\string.py", line 229, in format_prompt
    return StringPromptValue(text=self.format(**kwargs))
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\few_shot.py", line 165, in format
    return DEFAULT_FORMATTER_MAPPING[self.template_format](template, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\string.py", line 161, in format
    return self.vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\my_scripts\Invoice-Data-Extraction-Bot-using-LLAMA-2-and-Streamlit\virenv\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\utils\formatting.py", line 19, in vformat
    return super().vformat(format_string, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\string.py", line 165, in vformat
    result, _ = self._vformat(format_string, args, kwargs, used_args, 2)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\string.py", line 205, in _vformat
    obj, arg_used = self.get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\string.py", line 270, in get_field
    obj = self.get_value(first, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\string.py", line 227, in get_value
    return kwargs[key]
KeyError: '"properties"'

I have tried two different way but getting almost same error in other cases also.
1.
chain = few_shot_prompt | llm
chain_data = chain.invoke({{"raw_text": raw_text, "json_structure": json_structure}
print(chain_data)




chain = {"raw_text": RunnablePassthrough(), "json_structure": json_structure} | few_shot_prompt | llm  
chain_data = chain.invoke(raw_text)
print(chain_data)

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here or if have any other efficient way to do it let me know?
